# SQL server backup fail "A system assertion check has failed"

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2017

I just installed SQL Server 2017 EVAL in a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM. Most default options.

Default installation folder. SYSTEM databases in default folder. User databases in the D:\ drive.
Created some databases, some users, installed Brent Ozar and Ola Hallengren scripts. Next thing I was configuring the backups on the E:\ and getting an error. So i tried to run manually:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DABOL12] TO  DISK = N'E:\BACKUP\teste.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'DABOL12-Completo Banco de Dados Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

and getting this error:

```
Location:    mediaWrite.cpp:603
Expression:  (m_pWriteBuffer->GetCurrentSize ()% GetBlockSize ()) == 0
SPID:        56
Process ID:  1104
Mensagem 3013, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 1
BACKUP DATABASE está sendo encerrado de forma anormal.
Mensagem 3624, Nível 20, Estado 1, Linha 1
Falha em uma verificação de asserção do sistema. Verifique o log de erros do SQL Server para obter detalhes. Em geral, uma falha de asserção é causada por bug do software ou danos nos dados. Para procurar danos no banco de dados, considere a execução de DBCC CHECKDB. Se você concordou em enviar despejos à Microsoft durante a instalação, um minidespejo será enviado. Uma atualização poderá ser disponibilizada pela Microsoft no último Service Pack ou em um Hotfix do Suporte Técnico.

Horário de conclusão: 2020-08-13T21:57:22.6904999-03:00
```

Is in Portuguese, and telling me to check the SQL Server logs, which point me to [this dump file](https://pastebin.com/0BhhMN6p) where it have the same message but in english:

```
2020-08-13 19:07:27.81 spid54      Erro: 17066, Gravidade: 16, Estado: 1.
2020-08-13 19:07:27.81 spid54      SQL Server Assertion: File: <mediaWrite.cpp>, line=603 Failed Assertion = '(m_pWriteBuffer->GetCurrentSize ()% GetBlockSize ()) == 0'. This error may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures are not corrupted.
2020-08-13 19:07:27.81 spid54      Erro: 3624, Gravidade: 20, Estado: 1.
2020-08-13 19:07:27.81 spid54      A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details. Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a software bug or data corruption. To check for database corruption, consider running DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to Microsoft during setup, a mini dump will be sent to Microsoft. An update might be available from Microsoft in the latest Service Pack or in a Hotfix from Technical Support.
2020-08-13 19:07:27.81 Backup      Erro: 3041, Gravidade: 16, Estado: 1.
2020-08-13 19:07:27.81 Backup      BACKUP failed to complete the command BACKUP DATABASE DABOL12. Check the backup application log for detailed messages.
2020-08-13 19:13:11.98 spid54      **Dump thread - spid = 54, EC = 0x000000D63F84C160
2020-08-13 19:13:11.98 spid54      ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0035.txt
```

If I try to run this same command on the D:\ drive, it runs without any problems.

**Details:**

1. After getting the errors a few times, I installed CU21, but the error persist.
2. Both SQL Server and SQL Agent account have full control over E:\ drive. I went nuts and granted full control to everyone for the sake of testing.
3. I was pretty sure that the databases weren't corrupt, since I don't get the same error when backuping to another drive and had just created them), but I run the DBCC CHECK anyway, and it's everything ok.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 1**

This VM is hosted on a XenServer, which I'm not a admin nor have any access.
After finding out that I can successfully perform the backup to drives C: and D:, but could not perform to E:, I decided to check the devices.

Drive C: XENSRC PVDISK SCSI Disk Device
Drive D: XENSRC PVDISK SCSI Disk Device
Drive E: FreeNAS iSCSI Disk SCSI Disk Device

Searching a bit more a found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/2ofo4k/help_with_an_iscsi_issue/) with the same problem as I, shedding some light on the problem.

This is a SQL Server Bug, a Windows bug, a Xensrv bug or a FreeNAS bug?

Comment: The reddit post mention the use of MPIO and a SQL Server cluster. Are you using that too? Does the error occur if you try to [write something else from SQL Server on the disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275493/how-to-create-text-file-using-sql-script-with-text)? What if you try to create a database on that disk?  Does reading something from drive `E:` gives an error too? (like restoring a backup that you had pasted previously on drive `E:`? Just to be clear, I have no idea of what the problem could be, the tests are just to see if some new message would show the real problem.

Comment: No, i don't use any of that. I tried to create a database on ```E:``` and got error 5179. It seems that the volume is created with sectors of 128K, while SQL Server support up to 4K. I'll talk to the admin of the FreeNAS and see if he can recreate the volume with 4K sectors.

Comment: I guess you could also try specifying `MAXTRANSFERSIZE` explicitly and making sure that it is an exact multiple of 128K - (on the guess that this might control the write buffer size)

Comment: Nice. Were you able to fix the problem by recreating the volume with 4K sectors?